# React-slick modifications

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, slider, react-slick

I'm using react-slick and I'd like to add some features to my slider. 
I need some help to disable the left arrow on the initial state of the slider, since the slider is infinite. Also, I'm displaying 3 elements and I want to add a gradient mask on the 3rd one (the one that is following the current slide - the current slider has class slick-active).

I'm thinking about using `jQuery` but since this is not a good practice, any feedback  would be appreciated.

**React-slick:** https://react-slick.neostack.com

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use a slider that is not infinite, on the initial state the left arrow is disabled (class 'slick-disabled'). To hide it you can use CSS.
For the second one you can use the 'afterChange' prop ([This is an example](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/slide-change-hooks)).